# сложение значений в цикле

Tags: javascript

Как можно вывести сумму всех значений между тегами в зависимости от их количества в цикле?

например - есть 5 `div`ов со своими значениями, и их нужно приплюсовать. Цикл, думаю, нужен, т.к. количество блоков может меняться.

```
<div class="amount"> 1 </div>
<div class="amount"> 2 </div>
<div class="amount"> 3 </div>
<div class="amount"> 4 </div>
<div class="amount"> 5 </div>
```

js

```
window.onload = function(){
    var text = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < text.length; i++){
        sum = ++(text[i].innerHTML);      //тут не ясно 
      console.log(sum);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Чтобы из массива значений получить одно (в этой задаче – сумму), есть замечательный метод массива [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Т.к. `getElementsByClassName()` возвращает не массив, а некий объект NodeList, его сначала нужно преобразовать в массив, а потом применить `reduce()` с функцией, которая к «текущему» значению приплюсует значение из очередного поступившего на вход div'а.

Преобразовать массивоподобный объект в массив можно таким нехитрым трюком:

```
var myArray = Array.prototype.slice.call( massivoPodobnyObject)
```

Общий код в результате будет выглядеть так:

```js
function pluser(){
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(els).reduce( addMe, 0);
}

function addMe(p,c,i,a){
  // p - предыдущее значение общей суммы, c - очередной элемент массива
  return p + parseInt(c.textContent);
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '<div>Итого: ' + pluser() + '</div>';
}
```

```html
<div class="amount"> 1 </div>
<div class="amount"> 2 </div>
<div class="amount"> 3 </div>
<div class="amount"> 4 </div>
<div class="amount"> 5 </div>

<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: Красиво) но очень сложно для ТС, врядли он разберется  в вашем коде, исходя из уровня сложности его задачи

Comment: Пусть привыкает. Интересно, кто минус лепит, и зачем?

Comment: Не ясно зачем, у меня тоже минус, хотя плохого ничего не написал(

Comment: Привыкает - к чему? К раздутию кода магическим образом на пустом месте из желания "по-функциональничать"? Кстати, вам самому надо привыкать использовать анонимные функции там, где они к месту.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34134/discussion-on-answer-by-sergiks----).

Answer (score 5):

Первое: нужно обнулить переменную `Sum` чтобы было к чему прибавлять.
Второе: `text[i].innerHTML` это строка и надо привести ее к числу, лучше с помощью [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), или функции [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```
window.onload = function(){
    var text = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < text.length; i++){
        sum += Number(text[i].innerHTML);      //тут не ясно 
        console.log(sum);// внутри цикла выводится - каждую итерацию
    }
    console.log(sum);// снаружи цикла выводится - один раз
}
```

Пример

```js
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  sum += Number(text[i].innerHTML); //тут не ясно 
  console.log('Элемент №', i + 1, 'Сумма:', sum); // внутри цикла выводится - каждую итерацию
}
console.log('Итого', sum); // снаружи цикла выводится - один раз
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = 'Итого: ' + sum;
```

```html
<div class="amount">1</div>
<div class="amount">2</div>
<div class="amount">3</div>
<div class="amount">4</div>
<div class="amount">5</div>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: Лучше просто плюсом. Но одним.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я думаю так нагляднее :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var text = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < text.length; i++){
        sum += +(text[i].innerHTML);      //тут не ясно 
        console.log(sum);
    }
}
```

Вот правильный вариант

Comment: Не будет работать тк ты тут складываеш строки а не числа.

Comment: @sanu0074, ошибаешься _+(text[i].innerHTML)_ переводит в инт

Comment: @Grundy, А что тебе надо на выходе? ТС хочет получить сумму всех чисел что находятся внутри блоков

Comment: @Grundy, Ну и взгляни за одно, чем отличаются parseInt и Number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090518/what-is-the-difference-between-parseint-and-number

Comment: @sanu0074, а я знаю чем :-) в данном случае - не принципиально. И что не так с суммой?

Answer (score 3):

Если тебе нужно кол-во div'ов, то чем `text.length` тебя не устраивает? Это ж и есть кол-во блоков.

Результат должен быть таким:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var text = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < text.length; i++){
        sum += parseInt(text[i].innerHTML);      //тут не ясно 
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

Comment: извиняюсь не правильно выразился в начале( исправил вопрос. нужно взять все значения мужду тегами кажого дива

Comment: Тогда так: `sum += parseInt(text[i].innerHTML);`

Comment: тогда получится консоль выведет 4 значения, каждое из которых будет возрастать, по мере увлечения переменной i , тобишь надо получить только конечный вариант, когда имеем сумму всех

Comment: Для этого `console.log(sum);` используй после цикла, а не внутри

Comment: @sanu0074, стоит добавить код из комментариев в сам ответ, а то пока он не является ответом на вопрос

Comment: Внес правки в ответ

Comment: "Правки"? Теперь передрать код из чужих ответов, где он появился хронологически раньше - так и называется?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в комментарии этот код был почти в то же время, так что мне кажется имеет право, тем более функция другая используется

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Ну там где я кратко описал, раньше тех ответов - было ж кому-то не понятно? вот вам на радость если это так принципиально)

Comment: @Grundy, sanu0074, но при чем тут первое предложение ответа? Сейчас ответ состоит из двух несвязанных друг с другом кусков, первый из которых - бред полный.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, блин, специально для вас внес ясность! И ваши придирки излишни, я считаю ТС получил ответ, уже в полном объеме, и понял где он допустил ошибки

Comment: Теперь я вообще не вижу связи между первым советом и кодом.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> sum = ++(text[i].innerHTML);      //тут не ясно
> ```

Во-первых, один плюс стоит не там:

```
sum += +text[i].innerHTML;
```

во-вторых, будет правильнее брать текст, а не разметку:

```
sum += +text[i].textContent;
```

Ну и надо не забыть сделать где-то перед циклом

```
sum = 0;
```

Comment: _будет правильнее брать текст, а не разметку:_ мне кажется в данном случае не принципиально :)

Comment: кто-то молча минусует не объясняя причин :)

Answer (score 3):

Мои три копейки.:)

Функция работает, если браузер поддерживает `textContent` или `innerText`, то есть для широкого круга браузеров.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var values = document.getElementsByClassName("amount");
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0, count = values.length; i < count; i++) {
            sum += parseInt(values[i].textContent || values[i].innerText);
        }

        alert(sum);
    }
</script>
```

Если числа в тексте могут быть не только целыми, то вы можете заменить предложение

```
sum += parseInt(values[i].textContent || values[i].innerText);
```

на

```
sum += Number(values[i].textContent || values[i].innerText);
```

Comment: Да, вы правы, но скорее всего ваш ответ здесь заминусуют(

Comment: @sanu0074, не, посмотрите минусы почти у всех пропали

Comment: @Grundy, пока писал этот коммент, видел как уже у ответа Vlad from Moscow рейт стал отрицательным, сейчас уже плюсанули.... ужас какой-то происходит

Comment: @sanu0074, да нет 0/+1 все в порядке тут

Comment: зачем лыжи с `.innerText` – ведь IE >=9 поддерживает `.textContent`?

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, не знал, что можно посмотреть разбивку )

Comment: @Sergiks Я и написал: для широкого круга браузеров.:)

Comment: @Sergiks, да это привилегия со сколькой-то репутации начинается :) кроме того _innerText_ и _textContent_ вообще говоря разные результаты могут вернуть, по этому еще вопрос какой лучше, ну и насколько мне известно, _innerText_ другие браузеры тоже поддерживали

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('amount');
var sum = 0;  
for (var i = 0 ; i < text.length; i++){
      sum += Number(text[i].innerHTML);      //тут не ясно 
    console.log(sum);
    }
```

Comment: Не приводишь строки к численному типу, неправильно

Comment: @sanu0074, `Number(str)` как раз и приводит строку к числу

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, там ответ был отредактирован после комментария :)

Comment: @Rikaz - суммировать забыли

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, оу, это не к тому посту коммент влепил... я там выше писал чем отличаются parseInt и Number